# Drag & Drop an imageView thats in a UIView

Tags: swift, uiview, delegates, drag, drop

i am making a chess app and here is the main vc hierarchy:
MainViewController -> Board(UIView subclass) -> PieceView(UIImageView subclass) x 32 of my pieces.
I add the board to my viewController in viewDidLoad, which initializes the squares and the board(squares are just drawings).
the problem is that when i add Drag & Drop delegates to my Board, so it can handle the logic of moving the PieceView, it does not respond.

```
let dragInteraction = UIDragInteraction(delegate: self)
dragInteraction.isEnabled = true
PieceView.addInteraction(dragInteraction)

let dropInteraction = UIDropInteraction(delegate: self)
PieceView.addInteraction(dropInteraction)
```

i tried to set Board isUserInteractionEnabled and also PieceView's, all variations, still doesn't work.
it just doesn't even get to the delegation calls, so the code in them is irrelevant for that question.
what is the problem with my code? maybe subclassed UIImageView? or that the delegate of Drag & Drop is not the viewController? whatever it is, thank you for your answer.

maybe it helps that i've followed this tutorial with the idea of drag & drop :
[medium article](https://medium.com/@marklucking/a-simple-board-game-using-the-new-drag-and-drop-methods-5c6f4c3aea9d)

Answer (score 1):

the problem was that i expected it to work as a tap so i just did not drag properly, this question can be closed.
if you want to use drag & drop just remember : drag, not just tap.